# Switch video sources using button

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, html5-video

I want to view 3 different videos in the same video box by just click of a button(Change Video button). once i reach the third video and then press the button(Change Video button, the first video should be played again.
Can someone please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.
The code is attached

```
<button onclick="videoChanger()">Change Video</button>
<br>    
<video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerMeltdowns.mp4" controls></video>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    function videoChanger()
    {
        document.querySelector("video").src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4";
        document.querySelector("video").src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4";
    } //i tried this but this would change the video only once.
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code for videoChanger will immediately set the video element's src to the first and then the second video source. It's not particularly flexible for the real world but you could use an incrementing value to choose which one you want with flow control or array access.

For example, using an array:

```js
let myIndex = 0
let videoPrefix = 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/'
let myVideos = [
  'ForBiggerMeltdowns.mp4',
  'ForBiggerFun.mp4',
  'ForBiggerEscapes.mp4'
]

function videoChanger() {
  myIndex += 1
  if (myIndex >= myVideos.length)
    myIndex = 0
  document.querySelector("video").src = videoPrefix + myVideos[myIndex]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a slightly different approach whereby you have an array of video sources and a global integer variable that is used to access an item in the array of video sources. The variable is incremented each time the button is clicked and reset if it exceeds the length of the array.

```js
const path='http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/';
const oVideo=document.querySelector("video");
const srcs=[
  path+'ForBiggerFun.mp4',
  path+'ForBiggerEscapes.mp4',
  oVideo.src
];

let i=0;

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if( i > srcs.length - 1 )i=0;
  let src=srcs[i];
  oVideo.src=src;
  i++;
});
```

```html
<button>Change Video</button>
<video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerMeltdowns.mp4" controls></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all done with vanilla JS.  All I added to the video html was a custom attibute which tracks the video index to persist that over time. We call it initially to set the first video.

```js
function videoChanger() {
    
    const path = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/"
    
    const videos = ["ForBiggerMeltdowns.mp4", "ForBiggerFun.mp4", "ForBiggerEscapes.mp4"]
    
    const idx = document.querySelector("video").getAttribute("data-index");
     
    document.querySelector("video").src=path+videos[idx];
         
    document.querySelector("video").setAttribute("data-index", (idx+1) % videos.length);  
}
  
videoChanger();
```

```html
 <button onclick="videoChanger()">Change Video</button>
<video data-index=0></video>
```